# Make List with Rows that contain "1" value in particular columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I need to make 2 files with a list of rows containing "1" in certain columns- one file for column 4 "1"s and one for column 5 "1"s. The original file looks like this:

```
ID TreeID gC gD1 gD2.
36  1   0   0   0
36  2   1   0   0
36  3   1   0   0
36  4   1   0   0
36  5   1   0   0
36  6   0   0   1
36  7   1   0   0
36  8   1   0   0
36  9   1   0   0
36  10  1   0   0
36  11  1   0   0
```

I was thinking something like:

```
awk '$4%1' branch_36.cf.stat_tree.txt > gDF1_trees.txt
```

But I can't get it to work. My output would look something like (hopefully):

```
36  18  0   0   1
36  45  0   0   1
36  50  0   0   1
36  79  0   0   1
```

for `gDF2_trees.txt` and:

```
36  22  0   1   0
36  101 0   1   0
36  507 0   1   0
36  632 0   1   0
```

for `gDF1_trees.txt`.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why are you using `%` (modulo) instead of `==` (comparison)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. No images, no links, just plain text formatted as shown at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Again, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting for how to format your sample input/output (just like you formatted your code).

Comment: None of the rows in your sample input have a 1 in column 4 and none of the column 2 values in your 2 expected output files are present in your sample input. Please fix your question to show sample input and the output expected given that input (not some other output from some different input that you haven't shown us) so we have something that clearly demonstrates your requirements and we can test a potential solution using.

Comment: Hang on - are you trying to separate your input file by lines that have 1s in each of the 2 columns or are you trying to create output files that have 1s in each column regardless of what value they had in the input? Once you update your example it'll help make that clearer but please do clearly state your requirements in  your question.

Comment: I have over 5000 rows so I'm trying to show an example. I'm trying to create 2 new files from my input file that are simply all of the rows with a "1" in column 4 copied to one file, and all rows with a "1" in column 5 copied to another file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like this for changing the 4th column?

```
sed -E 's/^(([^ ]* ){3})[^ ]* (.*$)/\11 \3/g'
```

Just change the "3" within the curly brackets to 4, in order to change the 5th column.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out!

```
awk -F ' '  '$4 + 0 ==1' branch_36.cf.stat_tree.txt > gDF1_trees.txt
```

Comment: Your file does not use a single spaces for field delimiter. Given the data in your question, your `awk` command would output nothing.  Leave the field delimiter as the default (any number of consecutive spaces or tabs).  Also, there is no need to add zero to the value before comparing.  Your corrected could could be written as `awk '$4' infile >outfile` (assuming `$4` can only take the values `0` or `1`, otherwise `awk '$4==1' infile >outfile`).